# Behavior of "lid closing" with an external screen on Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian

I would like to obtain the following behavior on a laptop:

1. closing the lid should not suspend the computer
2. closing the lid should turn off the display
3. when closing the lid with an external display connected, I would like the system to "detect" the fact that the internal display is turned off and thus behave in "single screen mode" (all windows moved back to the external display, mouse cursor back on the display, etc.).

At the moment I obtained the correct behavior with the first two points by simply changing the settings.

Could you remind me what is the correct way to get 1. and 2. and point me in the correct direction for 3.?

Comment: Interesting, I already have this behaviour and want to get rid of it. For me, 1 was a simple system setting (except recently, when it turned on suspend for some reason after I connected and disconnected an external monitor, but that was solved with a quick Google search) and 2 is already the default. #3 is also default for me and the behaviour I want to get rid of. Can you give more details about your setup, like for example the laptop model, the connection to the screen (I use HDMI+adapter for a VGA monitor), etc.

Comment: @FabianRöling Thanks for the feedback. The laptop is a Lenovo P90 connected to a screen with mini display port to display port cable.