# How to stop internal laptop screen from turning off when closing lid?

Tags: debian, cinnamon, multi-monitor, laptop, monitors

When closing my laptop, it turns off the internal screen, which moves all windows to the second screen. I realise that I could move all windows to a secondary workspace to not have them overlap the one on the secondary screen and I also have a feature to turn off the screen backlight on my internal monitor, but both options are not quite as convenient as just closing the lid.

**Is there a way to keep the internal screen active with a closed lid?**

I'm using Debian 9.5 and Cinnamon 3.2.7 on a Schenker XMG A507-vsy laptop.
The monitor uses VGA and is connected to the HDMI slot of my laptop using an adapter (no extra power needed).

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446245/gnome-laptop-monitor-off-when-lid-closes) is likely related, but the answer doesn't really explain anything and I don't want to replace the entire display manager without knowing what all the changes are.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426184/behavior-of-lid-closing-with-an-external-screen-on-debian-9) is basically the opposite of my question, but unanswered.

Comment: Why I want this: I have most windows on the internal monitor and a video on the second. When I stop working with my laptop, I want to just close it and do other work without bothering too much with moving windows or finding a place for my laptop in its open state.

Comment: If someone knows how to find out what display manager I am currently using, I can also add that to the question.

Comment: Display manager is LightDM, I think.